# Generate C code from MATLAB code with external C++ code

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I am trying to generate C code from MATLAB code with some external C++ code. To debug my problem, I made a simple example. I created foo.cpp as:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
using namespace std;

double foo(double in1, double in2)
{
    return in1 + in2;
}
```

with header file named foo.h:

```cpp
double foo(double in1, double in2);
```

Then, I wrote a MATALB code:

```matlab
  function r = callfoo(x,y)
      r=1.1;
      if coder.target('MATLAB')
         % Executing in MATLAB, call MATLAB equivalent of
         % C function foo
          r = x + y;
      else
         % Executing in generated code, call C function foo
         coder.updateBuildInfo('addSourceFiles','foo.cpp');
         coder.cinclude('foo.h');
         r = coder.ceval('foo', x, y);
     end
  end
```

But it could not generate C code as I failed as I got this message from coder:

> Build error: C compiler produced errors. See the Build Log for further details.

When I pointed to more details, it pointed me to: https://www.mathworks.com/help///coder/ug/compiler-and-linker-errors.html

This example I took from Mathworks, actually (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.ceval.html). However, their external code is C, mine is C++.

How can I call the external C++ code from the generated C code?

Comment: What exactly failed, and did you get any error message? If so, please add it here.

Comment: @thisisbenmanley. Thanks for replying to me. I just edited the post.

Comment: It is telling you to see the Build Log, so it would be a good idea to check that out.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Hi. It actually pointed me to Compiler and Linker Errors which is very general: https://www.mathworks.com/help///coder/ug/compiler-and-linker-errors.html

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think you can call C++ code from C code. The other way around is easy though. Or you can compile your C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Cris MATLAB mentions C/C++ in their post: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.ceval.html. I am using the MATLAB coder from MATLAB. I am calling C++ from MATLAB code and generated C code by the coder.

Comment: I figured the problem. Added these to the header file (it is called mangling problem):  #ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

<all your function declarations>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif