# Generate C/C++ code from MATLAB code and a MEX file and dll files

Tags: c++, c, matlab, dll, mex

I am trying to generate C/C++ code from a MATLAB code in which a C++ source MEX file and some DLL files are used. I have the C++ source code but it seems I have to use ceval. My question is this possible to generate C/C++ code using coder given the problem I just stated?

I am reading around and this thread (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48620-generating-c-c-code-from-m-function-include-mex-file) says no. The solution in the thread is using ceval but it does not work well to my problem. The thread was in 2012. So any changes in 8-year long?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate C code from MATLAB code with external C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490956/generate-c-code-from-matlab-code-with-external-c-code)

Comment: @max The question you sent me the link is mine and is a bit different from this question that I include a MEX C++  source file. By the way, the answer to the linked question was found that it is a mangling problem though it was very painful to find it out.